# Connection timeout errors from Postgres Update Monitor (postgres 9.6)

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I am running PostgreSQL 9.6 on windows 10

It seems it has an update monitor that does not use any information about the proxy agent from Windows (we have a corporate proxy). It also does not look at the environment variables HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY (which I have set to add credentials via CNTLM for our corporate firewall). This is useful for programs such as NPM and GIT which need to get past our outgoing firewall.

So I am getting the following message every 10 or some minutes as a pop up from a program called:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\postgresql\updatemonitor\bin\UpdManager.exe" --execute  "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\stackbuilder.exe"
```

The message is very deceiving, but I tracked down the program, and it is the one listed above.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update Monitor** is a little utility from EnterpriseDB that notifies of needed updates. It is not very much documented and doesn't have any obvious way to configure itself. It can be considered *non essential*, in the sense that the database will perfectly work without it, and you will most probably not miss its functionality.

It's function is explained in the [EnterpriseDB website](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-update-monitor). EDB has also have a [Support Page](https://www.enterprisedb.com/services/support), with contact possibilities that *might* provide a solution to the malfunction of Update Monitor.

Being a non-essential utility (I've lived without it for very long), if it is giving some *annoying popups*, I'd consider that the  cost versus profit ratio is not favourable, and I'd recommend to, simply, **uninstall it**. The usual unistall process of any Windows 10 program should be sufficient.

In order to be "up to date" with regard to everything related to PostgreSQL development, it's good to [register to the "pgsql-announce@postgresql.org" mailing list from postgresql.org](https://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/subscribe/). They'll send one to three emails per week, neat and simple. Any critical update is always announced ASAP.

Answer (score 6):

While this answer does not resolve the current question, I think it could be useful for someone searching about Postgres timeout issues on DBA.SE or across the Internet.

According to [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html), you can use:

> `statement_timeout (integer)`
>
> Abort any statement that takes more than the specified number of 
>   milliseconds, starting from the time the command arrives at the server 
>   from the client. If `log_min_error_statement` is set to `ERROR` or lower, the 
>   statement that timed out will also be logged. 
>   A value of zero (the default) turns this off.
>
> Setting `statement_timeout` in `postgresql.conf` is not recommended because it would affect all sessions.

That means that you can set it in `postgres.conf` or you can use it in pgAdmin.

I've found an example in [Postgres community](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTi%3DBKcBKAwqyqpDh2xWP9h3irQsVGg%40mail.gmail.com).

```
set statement_timeout to 1000;
select pg_sleep(2);
```

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout

You can also have different timeout settings per user:

```
ALTER USER postgres SET statement_timeout=0
```

And even using a client session via libpq:
<sub>[From Postgres-XL](http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/config-setting.html)</sub>

> When starting a client session via libpq, parameter settings can be
>   specified using the `PGOPTIONS` environment variable. 
>   Settings established in this way constitute defaults for the life of the 
>   session, but do not affect other sessions. For historical reasons, the 
>   format of `PGOPTIONS` is similar to that used when launching the `postgres` 
>   command; specifically, the `-c` flag must be specified. For example,
>
> ```
> env PGOPTIONS="-c geqo=off -c statement_timeout=5min" psql
> ```